# Can't connect to Gmail with IMAPX using c#

Tags: c#, imapx

I'm following an example from IMAPX but it will not connect to GMAIL.
IMAP is enabled for the account and I've triple checked the username and password but it won't connect:

```
var server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
var login = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"]);
var password = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"]);

//create the IMAP CLient
var client = new ImapClient(server, true);

//connect to the server
if (!client.Connect())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to connect");
    return;
}

//login to the server
if (!client.Login(login, password))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid login");
    return;
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to use this library to connect to gmail? I have tried variations of "use SSL" and "verify certificate", but no mater what I try the login always fails.

Comment: Is the Google account sent up to allow access from "less secure" apps?

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider marking the this answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google by default does not allow "less secure" apps from account access unless the account is setup to allow it.

References:

- https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66025/what-are-the-dangers-of-allowing-less-secure-apps-to-access-my-google-account